# Poser une question « sur » ou « de » quelque chose

Tags: grammaire, prépositions

Est-ce que en français on pose des questions **sur** ou **de** qqch (*question about something*)?

> J'ai une question au sujet de ta lettre.

Cela me semble correcte

> J'ai une question **sur** ta lettre.
>
> J'ai une question **de** ta lettre.

Ces deux propositions sont-elles correctes? Il semble qu'elles ne le soient pas toutes les deux, n'est-ce pas?

Comment puis-je remplacer « *au sujet de* » dans ce cas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> J'ai une question sur ta lettre.

pourrait convenir mais

> J'ai une question au sujet de ta lettre.

est plus soutenu.

> J'ai une question de ta lettre.

n'est absolument pas correct.

On peut également dire :

> J'ai une question à propos de ta lettre.
>
> J'ai une question concernant ta lettre.

Comment: On peut aussi utiliser "à propos de ta lettre"

Comment: @GautierC: Effectivement, je l'ai ajouté.

Answer (score 1):

If faut dire:

> J'ai une question **sur** ta lettre.

Car ici "ta lettre" est l'objet de la question.

On utilise "de" après "question" quand "question" a le sens de "préoccupation":

> Il est question de ta lettre. (This is about your letter.)
>
> Il n'est plus question de revenir en arrière. (There is no way we go back.)
>
> C'est une question de point de vue. (It is a matter of point of view)
>
> Se pose la question de la place de l'individu dans la société.